# How can I uninstall ‘DB2 Enterprise Server Edition – SAPDB2SMP without the server crashing?

Tags: bsod, db2

In 'Control Panel | Programs | Programs and Features' of Windows Server 2008, I can see an entry for ‘**DB2 Enterprise Server Edition – SAPDB2SMP**’. When I select it and choose ‘Uninstall’, it goes though part of the uninstall process, then causes the server to have a blue screen and reboot.

There are no relevant logs in the Event Viewer.

The BSOD error details are:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name:                        BlueScreen
OS Version:                                          6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
Locale ID:                                             2057

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode:                                               f4
  BCP1:                                                    0000000000000003
  BCP2:                                                    FFFFFA801A335660
  BCP3:                                                    FFFFFA801A335940
  BCP4:                                                    FFFFF800027CB270
  OS Version:                                          6_1_7601
  Service Pack:                                       1_0
  Product:                                               272_3

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Windows\Minidump\081414-37705-01.dmp
  D:\usr\sap\SMP\tmp\2\WER-1033553-0.sysdata.xml
```

What can I do to diagnose and resolve this issue?

Comment: What is the BSOD error code? (Sorry can't comment yet. Need 50 rep points).

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling it in Safe Mode? There may be another installation interfering with the uninstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server administrators were able to remove it.

They are not sure why they could uninstall the application and I couldn't. They say that it may have been an authorisation issue, even though my user was a member of the Local Administrators group.